# Указатели, доступ к памяти c/c++

Tags: c++, c, указатели, память

Имеется следующий код, который успешно компилируется, но при выполнении вызывает исключение.

```
unsigned char *randomAddres = (unsigned char *) 0x33523;

    cout << "Here's your true random unsigned char value:" << *randomAddres << endl;
```

Ошибка при выполнении следующая:

> Exception thrown at 0x000B2A5F in DoomedProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00033523.

Почему нельзя разыменовать такой указатель? Связано ли это с ограничениями операционной системы?

Comment: Нельзя просто так взять и обратиться по любому адресу. Если сообщить какую задачу пытаетесь решить, Вам возможно подскажут правильное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, вы пытаетесь читать из памяти, к которой у вас нет доступа или которая вообще не выделена.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539388/can-i-access-random-data-with-random-memory-addresses-outside-of-my-c-program. В двух словах - да это ограничение ОС. Вы можете читать только ту память, которую ОС выделила вашему процессу (по крайней мере без специальных ОС-зависимых ухищрений)

Comment: @andy.37 это про межпроцессное взаимодействие через память. В данном случае, IMHO, вопрос скорее про доступ к своей памяти.

Comment: но мы же не можем гарантировать, что произвольный адрес попадет в "свою память". А межпроцессное взамодействие нужно организовывать с помощью вышеупомянутых ухищрений.

Comment: @andy.37: К межпроцессному вазимодействию это отношения не имеет. У каждого процесса своё адресное пространство, поэтому вы ни по какому указателю никак не сможете попасть в память чужой программы. (За исключением `MemoryMappedXXX`, но там вы уж сами знаете, что делаете.)